# What is the difference between the paint and draw methods in Java Applets?

Tags: java, swing, applet

I just want to know why both the paint and draw methods are used in Java Applet creation. What is the difference between them?

Comment: `Applet` has a `draw()` method?

Comment: thats what we're being told to do in my java class.

Comment: You should double check what your instructor means, as Applet has no draw method.

Comment: Do you mean `paint()` and `update()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When an applet is placed on a Web page, it is assigned a rectangular area on the page. It is the job of the applet to draw the contents of that rectangle.Similarly, when an applet needs to be drawn, the Web page calls the **paint()** routine of the applet.But there is no **draw()** method in applet.When you want to draw something, you should use **Graphics** class for example Graphics.drawLine(), Graphics.drawOval(), etc.

Answer (score 1):

`paint()` : Whenever there is a change in the state of the applet on the screen, paint() is called, paint() is also immediately called after start() method.

`draw()` : And it has methods like  drawRect(), drawImage() drawOval() related to Graphics class.